# How do I get my text on a single line when I rotate in CSS

Tags: css

[image]

I'm rotating a Cell with

```
height: 500px;
width: 20px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(270deg);
-o-transform:rotate(270deg);
transform:rotate(270deg);
```

But when my string contain more than 1 word, it's going on multi-line (like the picture below)

Comment: set up an example on jsfiddle.net please

Comment: 20px for width is really small.

Comment: Have you tried setting your `width` to `auto` or to a greater value?
[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/C3vWr/2/), try putting the width back to 20px on this fiddle.

Comment: Finally i'm putting my text in a div and I'm rotating the div in the cell wusing white-space: nowrap; on the div

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If what I have figured out is correct, try this,

add a `white-space: nowrap;` to your cell.

[jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/PszVM/), read about [white-space here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property ?

```
white-space: nowrap; /* or pre */
```

> **nowrap**
>
> Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.
>
> **pre**
>
> Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.

Simple example [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/54NZE/1/)

Comment: Thanks !  MDN is a great source for this kind of things, imo !